# BigQuery ML.DETECT_ANOMALIES with model 'arima_plus' returns only nulls

Tags: machine-learning, google-bigquery

I build a VERY simple model with only a time series and a data field of always 1 to find anomalies.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE MODEL `mytest.dummy`
OPTIONS(
    model_type='arima_plus',
    TIME_SERIES_DATA_COL='cnt',
    TIME_SERIES_TIMESTAMP_COL='ts',
    DATA_FREQUENCY='HOURLY',
    DECOMPOSE_TIME_SERIES=TRUE
)
AS
select ts, 1 cnt 
from UNNEST(GENERATE_TIMESTAMP_ARRAY('2022-05-01', '2022-05-02', INTERVAL 1 HOUR)) as ts;
```

Model works fine unless I use a custom `select` query to find anomalies. Even if the query is the exact same that was used to create the model.

```
SELECT * 
FROM ML.DETECT_ANOMALIES(
    MODEL `mytest.dummy`,
    STRUCT (0.9 AS anomaly_prob_threshold),
    (select ts, 1 cnt 
     from UNNEST(GENERATE_TIMESTAMP_ARRAY('2022-05-01', '2022-05-02', INTERVAL 1 HOUR)) as ts)
)
```

Result

| Row | ts | cnt | is_anomaly | lower_bound | upper_bound | anomaly_probability |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-05-01 00:00:00 UTC | 1.0 | null | null | null | null |
| 2 | 2022-05-01 01:00:00 UTC | 1.0 | null | null | null | null |
| 3 | .... |  |  |  |  |  |

Does anyone know what I need to do to get expected results of `is_anomaly = false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a closer look into the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-syntax-detect-anomalies) I found out that anomaly detection works only outside of the training range - at least for new queries and only as far as as the `HORIZON`goes (by the time of writing the default is 1.000).

Historical data can be also classified, but only without a query and only if the parameter `DECOMPOSE_TIME_SERIES` is set to `true`.

The example above would look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE MODEL `mytest.dummy`
OPTIONS(
    model_type='arima_plus',
    TIME_SERIES_DATA_COL='cnt',
    TIME_SERIES_TIMESTAMP_COL='ts'
)
AS
select ts, 1 cnt 
from UNNEST(GENERATE_TIMESTAMP_ARRAY('2022-05-01', '2022-05-02', INTERVAL 1 HOUR)) as ts;
```

The query with the next days

```
SELECT * 
FROM ML.DETECT_ANOMALIES(
    MODEL `mytest.dummy`,
    STRUCT (0.9 AS anomaly_prob_threshold),
    (select ts, 1 cnt 
     from UNNEST(GENERATE_TIMESTAMP_ARRAY('2022-05-03', '2022-05-04', INTERVAL 1 HOUR)) as ts)
)
```

Result

| Row | ts | cnt | is_anomaly | lower_bound | upper_bound | anomaly_probability |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-05-03 00:00:00 UTC | 1.0 | false | 1.0 | 1.0 | 0.0 |
| 2 | 2022-05-04 01:00:00 UTC | 1.0 | false | 1.0 | 1.0 | 0.0 |
| 3 | .... |  |  |  |  |  |